# Remove empty html tags with smarty

Tags: php, smarty

I want to remove all empty tags. Here's the regex which I've found here but it seems not to work in smarty.

```
regex_replace:"#<p[^>]*>(\s|&nbsp;|</?\s?br\s?/?>)*</?p>#":"";
regex_replace:"<(\w+)\s*.*?>\s*?</\1>#":"";
regex_replace:"<[^>]*>\s*<\/[^>]*>#":"";
```

Comment: I think you are missing the **#** as the first characters on the second and third regexes

Answer (score 0):

The regex should be:

```
regex_replace:"#<p[^>]*>(\s|&nbsp;|</?\s?br\s?/?>)*</?p>#":"";
regex_replace:"#<(\w+)\s*.*?>\s*?</\1>#":"";
regex_replace:"#<[^>]*>\s*<\/[^>]*>#":"";
```

The `#` was missing as @user2182349 mentioned.